# Conda packages not recognised by conda build?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, conda-build

I am trying to create a conda package using conda build and a meta.yaml file. Most of the dependencies are handled just fine but some of them are causing issues. I know these packages all work together because I am using them in my dev environment.

My requirements section for the yaml file is as follows:

```
requirements:
  build:
    - setuptools
    - numpy
    - python >=3.6
    - matplotlib
    - rdkit
    - openforcefield
    - openeye
    - networkx
    - psi4
  run:
    - numpy
    - python >=3.6
    - matplotlib
    - rdkit
    - openforcefield
    - openeye
    - networkx
    - psi4
```

All of the packages causing issues (see error below) are installable through conda, for example:

`conda install -c psi4 psi4`

`conda install -c omnia openforcefield`

`conda install -c openeye openeye-toolkits`

`conda install -c rdkit rdkit`

However when calling `conda build .` I get the following error:

`conda_build.exceptions.DependencyNeedsBuildingError: Unsatisfiable dependencies for platform linux-64: {'rdkit', 'openeye', 'psi4', 'openforcefield'}`

I believe the rest of the .yaml is correct as there have been no errors raised with respect to anything else. Do I need to be more specific/use some special code for identifying package names? Or perhaps the issue is something else.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

I believe I have found the issue.

The above packages all come from different channels. Having added all of the channels I now get further through the build process. Channels are added with:

```
conda config --add channels <name of channel>
```

There may be an issue when it comes to distributing the package though. I think other people might have to add all the other channels as well.